# linq with entity framework - translate from SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4

I want to translate the following request to linq with entity framework:

```
SELECT * 
FROM productivite
INNER JOIN Clients
ON Clients.ClientName = productivite.action and Clients.Responsable ='resp1'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = from p in productivite
              join c in clients on p.clientname equals c.action
              where c.responsable == "resp1"
              select p, c;
```